# At what kind of rate does $e^{\log(x)^2}$ increase?

Tags: probability, asymptotics

If you look at the [LogNormal distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) PDF, take $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$ and get rid of constant multipliers, you're left with:

$$\frac{1}{x e^{\log(x)^2}} \tag{1}$$

We can also see from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) that it has a mean, variance, skewness and kurtosis.

This means the function above probably decays faster than $\frac{1}{x^4}$. Let's simplify things further and inquire about just $e^{\log(x)^2}$. It must increase faster than $x^3$. I suspect it increases faster than any polynomial. Which would be mildly surprising since $e^{\log(x)}$ is just $x$.

Is there an easy way to see this? I tried Taylor expanding it about $x=1$, but the differentiation got very messy very fast.

Comment: Taking the $\log$ on both sides and simplifying, you can find it easier to conclude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your function grows faster than any polynomial, which becomes strikingly clear if you rewrite it as $x^{\log x}$ (since $\log x$ grows without bound). To show this formally, let's make precise what we'd like to prove. Let's say we want to show that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists $M>0$ such that if $x>M$, $x^{\log x}>x^n$. Assuming that $x>1$ for our purposes, taking $M=e^n$ works, since this implies that $x^{\log x}>x^{\log e^n}=x^n$ for all $x>M$.